# Is there a way to populate enum from properties file in java/springBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, dynamic, enums, properties

I have an enum as below

```
public enum Alphabet {
    ABC("abc"), XYZ("xyz"),         
    private final String alpha;

    public String getAlpha() {
        return alpha;
    }
    
    Alphabet(String alpha) {
        this.alpha = alpha;
    }
}
```

This is helpful when I know the values beforehand but fails if the values need to be changed so I want a solution where either the enum gets populated by the values from properties file(if possible) or maybe a different way where I can replace this enum with a better and efficient way of dealing with dynamic addition or removal of the values.

Comment: Enums are static, they're determined at compile time. If you're trying to make "dynamic enums", that doesn't exist.

Comment: An enum is a *fixed* set of known values, so no you can't create them dynamically

Comment: Why don't you use the properties from your file as `java.util.Properties` ?

Answer (score 0):

## Enum definition is fixed, unchanging

You said:

> if the values need to be changed

Enums in Java are defined at compile-time. The named objects defined in an enum cannot be added or removed at runtime.

## Collections

You said:

> a better and efficient way of dealing with dynamic addition or removal of the values.

If at runtime you need to define a modifiable group of related objects of the same type, use a [`Collection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collection.html) such as [`List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html) or [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html). To track pairings of objects, use [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html).

Comment: Sure, I was thinking of the same but then I want to know will it affect the performance of the code in any way if I replace enum with let's say Map?

Comment: @Codeblocks Performance is irrelevant, as enums and maps serve two different purposes. And, anyways, accessing a limited set of objects either by enum name or by map key is extremely unlikely to be a bottleneck in your code. Beware of *premature optimization*. Usually the best way to optimize is to write simple straightforward code that happens to also be easy to read and comprehend — then let the Java compiler and runtime optimize. If, after that, you suspect a performance problem, use profiling tools to prove and pinpoint the problem.